# Minecraft Forge 1.16 Get Blockdamage Progress

Tags: minecraft-forge

I can't figure out how to read the blockbreak progress in minecraft forge version 1.16. I know the function DestroyBlockProgress and the variant with hashmaps, but I can't find out how this works. a little tip or an example would help me a lot

Thanks